# OpenGL draws over widgets in Qt

Tags: c++, qt, opengl-es

I'm developing a Qt app which uses Cocoa on the Mac and am using PowerVR SDK to enable OpenGL ES 2.0 on Mac Desktop.

I've managed to get it working, everything renders perfectly, the problem is
that when I'm creating a widget in that window, OpenGL renders over it, e.g
I'm creating a QLabel and it renders over it, making the label invisible.

I tried calling QLabel's repaint() method after rendering a single OpenGL frame, but that didn't help.

Has anyone encountered such or similar issue and has any suggestions?

Thanks!

Comment: Same issue, under windows too. OpenGL is drawing even over toolbars.

Comment: _I've managed to get it working, everything renders perfectly, the problem is that when I'm creating a widget in that window_

What are you using to create "that window"?

Comment: @LukasT A class that extends QMainWindow, basically it's a Qt window that wraps around Cocoa, and I'm passing the value returned by winId() to eglCreateWindowSurface

Comment: @MaxRaskin Well, you need QOpenGLWidget for OpenGL window.

Answer (score 1):

If you wish widgets to interoperate with OpenGL content, you must use the `QOpenGLWidget`. It draws to an offscreen buffer that then gets composited with the widgets.

Alternatively, you must yourself render the label into a texture, and apply the texture to a quad.

Comment: I wish I could do that, but I'm using constrained to using an OpenGL driver from PowerVR, and it fails to interoperate with QOpenGLWidget, the alternative way is too expansive

Comment: @MaxRaskin "the alternative way is too expensive" It's not. It can't be. What do you think is involved? Qt does all widget composition in software. In the best case, the label is doing opaque drawing on the window's backing store. When you render it to a `QImage`, you're doing the same thing - remember that the backing store 's paint device is just a `QImage`!  Moreover, you only need to render the label when its text or styling changes. It's as low cost as it gets.

Comment: I meant expensive in implementation time, not in performance, I meant whether there is any less complex way of doing that

Comment: no, but label was just a private case, consider a text box, that is not so trivial to implement

Comment: @MaxRaskin All of these have identical implementation: you include the widget in event processing for input/focus/user interaction, and render it in a texture that goes onto the quad. Any widget can be used.